# PaperTrail and Octopus - Specify connection for versions table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So far I can do this in console to make it work:

```
PaperTrail::Version.table_exists?
=> false
PaperTrail::Version.octopus_establish_connection Octopus.config[Rails.env][:ms]
PaperTrail::Version.table_exists?
=> true
```

Where and how can I put:

```
PaperTrail::Version.octopus_establish_connection Octopus.config[Rails.env][:ms]
```

I tried to put it in `app/models/papertrail_version.rb` and in `config/initializers/papertrail.rb`, but in model is not loaded, and in initializers it fails because Octopus has not been bundled yet, I suppose I could bundle it in initializer, any advice on how to get this as simple as possible.

## Update

I tried in initializer with no luck:

```
require 'octopus'
PaperTrail::Version.octopus_establish_connection Octopus.config[Rails.env][:ms]
```

I am getting this when trying to run rails console:

```
/vagrant/config/initializers/papertrail_version.rb:3:in 
`<top (required)>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `app/models/paper_trail/version.rb`:

```
module PaperTrail
  class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
    octopus_establish_connection Octopus.config[::Rails.env][:ms]
  end
end
```

Note I had to use `::` in `Rails.env`

## Update

I had to require file in an initializer because of Rails load process `require Rails.root.join 'app/models/paper_trail/version'`